# Match each nodes class name [javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am searching some questions but no luck,,
How to match each class name with other nodes dynamically with plain javascript or jQuery, if `img.bg` with `data-index="1"` has class `load` or `fail`, than `div.ct` with `data-index="1"` will add a class `load` or `fail` , and so on...

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bg">
    <img class="bg load" data-index="1" src="img-1.jpg">
    <img class="bg fail" data-index="2" src="img-2.jpg">
    <img class="bg load" data-index="3" src="img-3.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="cts">
    <div class="ct load" data-index="1"></div>
    <div class="ct fail" data-index="2"></div>
    <div class="ct load" data-index="3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Isn't that already the case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want

```
$('.ct').each(function(
     var $img = $('.bg[data-index='+$(this).data("index")+']');
     $(this)
     .toggleClass("load", $img.hasClass("load"))
     .toggleClass("fail", $img.hasClass("fail"));
});
```